# How to get Keypad to be displayed on app startup?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I'm building a password vault type app for iOS, and I was wondering how do you setup your app to where a decimal keyboard pops up as soon as the app is opened? Do I just use a UITextfield object and call the .secureTextEntry property on it? I want to make this programmatically and not in storyboard.

Comment: Yes, you have to create a `UITextField` and focus on it. Make sure you chose the number pad as the keyboard type.

Comment: Ok yes, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force the keyboard to show, you need to call this function becomeFirstResponder()

Code sample:

```
// Create a UITextField in your first UIViewController when app shows up.
let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
view.addSubview(textField)
// Force keyboard to show on screen
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: No worries banngs, please accept my answer if it helped you.